# Difference between to_char(FILE_CREATION_DT,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and between to_char(FILE_CREATION_DT,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MM:SS')

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

What is the difference between

```
to_char(FILE_CREATION_DT,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

and between

```
 to_char(FILE_CREATION_DT,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MM:SS')
```

as I have observed the Result in both the cases are different.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

Comment: What difference have you actually observed?

Answer (score 3):

MI and MM represent different elements of a datetime:

```
MI = Minute
MM = Month   (Month number 1-12 rather than the short month name you get with MON)
```

Here's a source list:  [Oracle Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm)